# Run a Java for a particular amout of time

Tags: java

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
Command nextCommand = getNextCommandToExecute();
}
```

I want to run the above program for 60 minutes. So instead of for loop I need to do something like-

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    do{
    Command nextCommand = getNextCommandToExecute();
    } while (durationOfTime is 60 minutes);
```

But I am not sure, how should I make this program to run for 60 miniutes.

Comment: Can you show me one example by using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: just calculate the diff from start and current time before each condition test.

Comment: @usoban What if it is one continuous task? You won't get control back until after the task is done, if ever.

Comment: that is true, however he did not state that in the question.

Comment: Can anyone explain me what can be the problem with do while loop logic? As skynorth is saying there can be some problem?

Comment: It only checks the time after each command ends.  If the commands take 10 seconds, no problem.  If each command takes 2 hours, it runs for 2 hours.  If it takes 55 minutes, it will run for 110 minutes.(Checks after 55, says ok to continue, then runs for another 55)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach. Why exactly don't you do it just that way? Except, don't use `nanoTime`, use `currentTimeMillis`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long endTime = startTime + (60*60*1000);

while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
    Command nextCommand = getNextCommandToExecute();
}
```

One drawback with this method is if the `Command` you are trying to execute runs past the 60 minute timer or never finishes at all. If this behavior is not allowed, you are better off implementing a thread that interrupts whatever thread is running this loop.

Comment: Like I said to the other person - " What if it is one continuous task? You won't get control back until after the task is done, if ever"

Comment: @skynorth Thanks! Addressed in an edit. May or may not be an issue for the op, depending on other requirements of the program.

Answer (score 4):

Launch a background thread that sleeps for 60 minutes and exits:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60 * 60 * 1000L);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ignore: we'll exit anyway
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
new Thread(r).start();
<your original code here>
```

Comment: So in this where I will be executing my command as if you look into my example I need to perform some tasks and after 60 minutes, I want to stop the program.

Comment: See my edit. You start the thread before executing your original code.

Comment: Note that using this method your final command can get killed in the middle of its execution.  If you analyze any output, you'll probably want to omit the last command as it will be incomplete.

Comment: @Nevzz03, This is a very crude way of stopping your program, but works.

Comment: @skynorth You complain about people showing code that doesn't stop the task in progress, and now you complain about the code that does. You know there is no right way to do this. `Thread.interrupt` is just advisory, so again you can go on complaining.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You are right. I was relying on calling interrupt() and assuming the Thread won't be blocked on an IO, network or some other call. A better way to do this is to place a volatile variable in the command to be executed that it will check periodically, but probably might not be possible in OP's case. I upvoted this answer. I was merely warning that calling System.Exit(0) IS a very crude way of ending a task, won't you agree?.

Comment: @skynorth It definitely is, and dangerous. That's why I think `do {} while (System.currentTimeMillis()<stopTime)` is just right.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Also my main concern is that no one warned OP that this only works for tasks that compute for lass than the limit time. That is all. Ok, anyways, I think OP got what he was looking for.

Comment: @skynorth People may have been guided by OP's first example, `for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)` which does indicate that OP has short-running tasks in mind.

Answer (score 2):

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
do 
{
  //stuff
} while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 1000*60*60);
```

Comment: Like I said to the other person - " What if it is one continuous task? You won't get control back until after the task is done, if ever"

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
do {
    Command nextCommand = getNextCommandToExecute();
} while ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) < 60 * 60 * 1000000000L);
```

Please note `System.nanoTime()` is slightly different from using `System.currentTimeMillis()` not only in the scale, but also in what it measures: `System.nanoTime()` is the elapsed time, and `System.currentTimeMillis()` is the system time (wall clock). If the system time changes, `System.currentTimeMillis()` doesn't work as expected. (This doesn't apply to summertime change however, as the returned value is UTC / GMT.)

`1000000000L` nanoseconds is one second. Please note the `L` for `long`. In Java 7 you could also write the more readable `1_000_000_000L`.

Comment: Like I said to the other person - " What if it is one continuous task? You won't get control back until after the task is done, if ever"

Comment: maybe getNextCommandToExecute() is blocking, so if there's no commands programm will not shutdown. Also an empty infinite loop is bad idea. Try to use `Thread.sleep(60*60000L)` in background thread

Comment: The code above is the answer for the original question. The question (at least originally) was not about creating a new thread or executing things in the background, or about what if getNextCommandToExecute() blocks or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

do{
Command nextCommand = getNextCommandToExecute();
}while (startTime < startTime+60*60*1000);
```